# Extracting data using multiple header tags with stomp

Tags: python, stomp

I am doing some work in pushing energy trading data to ActiveMQ. I am using the stomp.py library to catch the data. The code below works and extracts all the data with the data tag "BOALF". I need to make the code search for multiple tags (10 total). For example the tag "BOD" and "SEL".

I need to rewrite the code: `headers={'selector': "JMSType='BOALF'"}`, but I am not sure how to include several tags as all my attempts have resulted in error.

```py
import stomp
import time

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):

    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print(type(headers))
        for k, v in headers.items():
            print('header: key %s , value %s' % (k, v))
            print('received a message "%s"' % message)
            with open("messages.log", "a") as logfile:
                logfile.write(message)



conn = stomp.Connection12(host_and_ports=[('api.bmreports.com', 61613)], use_ssl=True)

conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.start()

# Api key is being passed as both username and password.
conn.connect('XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXX', True)
conn.subscribe(destination='/topic/bmrsTopic', ack='auto', id=545668, 
               headers={'selector': "JMSType='BOALF'"})

while conn.is_connected():
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Does `headers={'selector': "JMSType='BOALF'", 'key2': "foo"}` not work?

Comment: But what should you place as key2? dictionary keys are unique so i cant use selelctor against. and would foo would be "JMSType='BOD'" for example? i cant see how that should work

Comment: What broker are you using?

Comment: ActiveMQ  is the broker

Comment: If you happen to remember, how did you find you how to set the header to `'selector': "JMSType='BOALF'"` ? i was unable to find the specification for this either in bmrs docs or in activemq docs.

Comment: Answered my own question very quickly once i knew what to search for. Its specified at the bottom of [this](https://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) activemq documentation page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selector` header feature of ActiveMQ uses SQL 92 syntax as specified in the JMS 1.1 specification and described in [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) for `javax.jms.Message`. In your case you can do this:

```
JMSType in ('BOALF','BOD','SEL')
```